# How to show the progress bar when i am uploading a excel sheet using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to show the progress bar like

uploading 1 out of 100 in the progress bar while uploading an excel sheet containing 100 records

and it should be incremented

Comment: uploading where how and with what????

Comment: Okay, so set the max range to 100 and update it with the number of records uploaded (update every 5 - 10 records).

Comment: Uploading in Sql database with oledbconnection and with sqlbulkcopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this document which details an event you can hook into with SqlBulkCopy to report progress after X rows have been inserted.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.notifyafter.aspx

You could use this event to update the `ProgressBar.Value` (which is an integer 1-100) to the current progress.

Comment: actually i am using asp.net and in the OnSqlRowsCopied() event, i cant able to find my textbox id